# Do I need an adapter to connect this sprayer to my pneumatic compressor?

Tags: compressor, air

I don’t know what these connectors are called but when I connect my compressor to the spray head via the male connector it doesn’t seem like a solid connection and leaks air. Is there something else I should use? [image: air sprayer connector]

[image: compressor connection]

Comment: If that's a finish (paint, lacquer, ...) sprayer then you may want a coalescing filter and other bits'n'bobs to keep compressor oil and other contaminants out of the finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top one is a hose barb.  You slip a hose with a hose clamp onto it and tighten the clamp.

The bottom one is a female half quick connect/push-in connect.  You need the matching male half.

There are a few different designs and I do not think all of them work together/mix match together.

Comment: Thanks for the help here, I bought the right part and everything works great now!

Answer (score 2):

You need both the male and female fittings to be matched.  The best bet is to buy them in a set.  [Male and female set is here](https://www.harborfreight.com/brass-industrial-quick-coupler-starter-set-5-piece-56710.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19224063582&campaignid=19224063582&utm_content=147938321201&adsetid=147938321201&product=56710&store=144&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7PCjBhDwARIsANo7CgliHKyNIhK-gaIL9qeeM8gI5HL-CRonHnI9i8GVHTxpbr-djTcW2lkaAnVFEALw_wcB)

Some stores have a color coded tape on the fittings.  Buy a male and female fitting with the same color and they will work together.